# If value of one dictionary is the same as key of the second dictionary sum second dictionary values Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to sum the values of the second dictionary depending on the first dictionary. If I have dictionaries A and B.

```py
A = {"Mark": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "June": ["e", "a"], "John": ["a", "b", "f"]}
B = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 0, "e": 3, "f": 2}
```

What the result should be is:

```
Mark=6, June = 4, John = 5
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the values in list of first dictionary for a key is present as a key in the second dictionary and then you can use `list comprehension` and `sum` function to get the job done. Something similar to this:

```
A = {"Mark":["a", "b", "c", "d"], "June":["e", "a"], "John":["a", "b", "f"]}
B = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':0, 'e':3, 'f':2}
for k,v in A.items():
    total = sum([B[eachV] for eachV in v if eachV in B.keys()])
    print(f'{k}: {total}')
    
Mark: 6
June: 4
John: 5
```

**UPDATE:**
Pointed by: @Mushif Ali Nawaz

If your data is going to be larger, you can consider using generator comprehension instead of list comprehension, for it is faster..

```
total = sum(B[eachV] for eachV in v if eachV in B.keys())
```

List comprehension changes to generator comprehension when square brackets are replaced by parenthesis.

Comment: `List` comprehension can be replaced with `generator` comprehension, it's more efficient for a large dataset.

Comment: And when passing generator comprehension to the `sum` function, you can even omit the generator parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```py
for key, value in A.items():
    _sum = 0
    for val in value:
        _sum += B[val]
    print(key, '=', _sum)
```

Output:

```
Mark = 6
June = 4
John = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your question interesting, please review my answer if you found it beneficial.

```
A = {"Mark":["a", "b", "c", "d"], "June":["e", "a"], "John":["a", "b", "f"]}
B = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":0, "e":3, "f":2}



result_list = []

for i in A.keys():
    result = 0
    for j in A.get(i):
        result = result + B.get(j)
    result_list.append(result)

print("final result  = ",dict(zip(A.keys(), result_list)))
```

Output:

```
final result  =  {'Mark': 6, 'June': 4, 'John': 5}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. These are all helpful. Another question is how do I create new dictionary from above two dictionaries if there is another key that has : A = {"Mark": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "June": ["e", "a"], "John": ["a", "b", "f"], "Mary':['w'}, that has no value in another dictionary. In new dictionary this should be ignored and only report Mark: 6 June: 4 John: 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
A = {"Mark": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "June": ["e", "a"], "John": ["a", "b", "f"]}
B = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 0, "e": 3, "f": 2}
r = {a:sum(B[i] for i in b) for a, b in A.items()}
```